# Copy large array or change access index

Tags: arrays, performance, fortran

Apologies if this is question has an obvious answer but I can't phrase it properly to find an answer online.

In Fortran, suppose I have an array (>100,000) of real numbers. I will continuously access this array (in a consecutive manner) over and over again throughout one step of a time integration scheme. Each subsequent steps some elements of this array will no longer be needed. I do not know how many, it could be anywhere from none of them to all of them. My question is:

Is it better to: (1) Go through this array every step and copy the remaining elements I need to a new array, even though only a very small percentage might need to be taken out, or (2) should I have a new array of integer indexes which I update every timestep to access this array. My understanding is that if the memory access is consecutive it should be very quick and I think this should outweigh the cost of copying the array. On the other hand updating the integer indexes would be very speedy but the cost would be that the data would then be fragmented and accessing it would be slower.

Or is this the type of question with no definitive answer and I need to go and test both methodologies to find which is better for my application?

Comment: It is always better to show real code than just long description in words. It is too long, too boring, too ambiguous. (TLDR)

Comment: I suspect the answer here is indeed to just try it and see. In my experience  indexing with lookup arrays can lead to significantly worse performance. An alternative approach would be to implement a linked list that you can update as you remove elements, however I suspect this will also lead to worse performance -- but again I think it really depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say beforehand, so the easy answer would indeed be *"Measure!"
Some speculation might help with *what* to measure, though. Everything that follows under the assumption that the code is performance critical indeed.

**Memory Latency:**
100k elements does usually exceed L1 and L2 cache, so memory locality will play a role. OTOH, a linear scan is way better than a scatter access.

*If* memory latency is significant compared to the per-element operations, *and*  the majority of elements become "uninteresting" after a given number of iterations, I would aim at:

- mark individual elements as "to be skipped in future iterations"
- compact the memory (i.e. remove skippable elements) when ~ 50% of the elements become skippable

(Test for above conditions: for a naive implementation, does the time of a single iteration grow faster-than-linear with number of elements?)

**Cache-friendly blocks:**
*If* memory latency is an issue *and* it is possible to apply multiple operations to a small chunk (say, 32KiB of data), do so.

**Parallelization:**
(the elephant in the room). Can be added easily if you can process in cache-friendly blocks.

Comment: I very much like the idea of marking elements and then cleaning up once a threshold is hit. This seems to use the best of both worlds!

Comment: Would love to see the results, whether it makes any difference at all etc.!